# Looking for way to copy first line of text file to end of every line

Tags: text-processing

Is there a way to copy the first line in a text file to the end of every line? - could include copying line 1 to the end of line 1 if it simplifies things.

```
 I have:

 __1
 2
 3

 I want:


 1
 2__1
 3__1

 or 

 1__1
 2__1
 3__1
```

It has to be easily modified to handle multiple files.

Any suggestions?

Big thanks.

Comment: Thanks I was searching for every line and the above duplicate post used each - thanks for finding it.

Answer (score 0):

With `awk`:

To append the first line of each file to every line of the same file:

```
awk 'FNR == 1 {suffix=$0} {print $0suffix}' file1 file2 file3
```

To leave the first line alone:

```
awk 'FNR == 1 {suffix=$0} FNR != 1 {print $0suffix}' file1 file2 file3
```

To append the first line of `file1` to every line of several files:

```
awk 'NR==1' {suffix=$0} {print $0suffix} file1 file2 file3
```